# Foreach act wierd

Tags: php, css, foreach

i try to make an simple way to create an box in a class.
The problem is , it only give me the first element in the array. I echo out the $values and i get the whole css code and i try to place them in style at div. But still get only the last element.

My currently code looks like:

```
class general {
    public function box($content,$style,$width = 50,$height = 50) {

            foreach ($style as $k => $v) {
                    $values = ''.$k.':'.$v.';';
                        echo($values);
                $box = '<div class="testBox" style="'.$values.'">'.$content.'</div> ';        
            }
            return $box;
    }
}

$general = new general();
$test = array(
     'background-color' => '#000',
     'font-size' => '120px'
);
echo $general->box('testValue',$test);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public function box($content,$style,$width = 50,$height = 50) {
    $values = '';
    foreach ($style as $k => $v) {
        $values .= ''.$k.':'.$v.';';
    }
    $box = '<div class="testBox" style="'.$values.'">'.$content.'</div> ';
    return $box;
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped :) I'd appreciate if you accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$box = '<div class="testBox" style="'.$values.'">'.$content.'</div> ';
```

to

```
$box .= '<div class="testBox" style="'.$values.'">'.$content.'</div> ';
```

And declare

`$box = '';`  outside the loop.

You need to concate the data using `.`

Comment: Thanks for answer, did not work some how. But Tony did give me right answer. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Right I thought  u are returning multiple div. But u are returning one div by adding multiple tags. +1 for Tony and select his answer !!